# Selecting div with class inside div that has id

Tags: css, html, selector

```
<div id="special-image">
    <div class="image-itself"></div>
    <div class="image-info"></div>
</div>
```

Nor `#special-image.image-itself` neither `#special-image .image-itself` aim the first `div` inside.

Comment: The second one looks fine, and should work.  `#special-image .image-itself`.  Perhaps the issue lies somewhere else?

Comment: `#special-image .image-itself` should be the right selector. If that's not working, then there's somehow something else wrong somewhere.

Comment: YES, the code in action was not what I had written here, my bad I'd closed the `div#special-image`, so `image-itself` was not really a child of that. Thank you for mentioning me my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the second one is correct.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3B8QX/).

I added a little `css` to it and it shows.
You might have a problem somewhere else.